# Getting database object in Django python

Tags: python, mysql, django

The following is my database model:

```
id | dept | bp | s | o | d | created_by | created_date
```

`dept` and `bp` together have an unique index for the table. This means there will always be 30 different records in the database under the same `dept` and `bp`. I was trying to do an update function on the records, by getting the object first. The following is the way I tried to get the object:

```
try:
    Sod_object = Sod.objects.get(dept=dept_name, bp=bp_name)
except Sod.DoesNotExist:
    print "Object doesn't exist"
    msg = "Sod doesn't exist!"
else:
    for s in Sod_object:
        # Do something
```

But it's always giving me 30 records (obviously). How can I make this a single object? Any suggestions?

Comment: Add another field to `unique_together` list that will make each record *really* unique.

Comment: Why are there 30 records for same unique values?

Comment: Because the database table is not normalized. Its a one table with many values. By right one dept-bp object will have 30 objects in another table.

Comment: How can use `unique_together` ozgur?. I mean in my code?

Comment: I have already updated my model with `class Meta:
        unique_together = ('dept', 'bp')`

Comment: @vellattukudy You say it's giving you thirty objects, but you're using `Sod.objects.get()`, [`get()` should only return one object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#get), otherwise it will throw an `MultipleObjectsReturned` error. Are you sure your code is correct? Or do you mean you want all thirty objects to be returned, but it's only returning one?

Comment: You are right Bono. Get shud return only one object. But as per my db design no normalization been done. Each 30 records are identified by 2 fileds dept and bp. That will be same for all the 30 objects. For another 30 objects the values for dept and bp will be different or may be bp will be the same but dept will be definitely different. So I want to get an object based on the dept and bp. Thats what i supposed to do there in that piece of get code. SInce the dept and bp are same for 30 records, its returning 30 records. Anyway to solve that Bono?

Comment: what if I use filter?

Comment: Your description is incorrect, you are saying *"have an unique index for the table"* but then you say *"there will always be 30 different records"*. If they have a unique index (i.e. `unique_together`) there will only be a max of one record. And `.get()` will only ever return one record or raise an exception if not exactly one record is found. Please post your model or correct the description of it in your question.

Comment: Code is wrong and giving me the exact error u told me

Comment: C14L: Yes there is 30 different records under `one dept-bp pair`

Comment: `dept-bp` will be same fpr that 30 records and another 30 will have different `dept-bp` pair

Comment: @vellattukudy Then they do not have a unique index set.

Comment: yeah, hope so. index is the `id` shown in the database. It shudnt be correct, by right the index will be `dept-bp` pair

Comment: @vellattukudy You are asking *"How can I make this a single object?"* Do you mean that you want to combine the 30 records into one, or are you looking for a way to address individual records? In the later case, you can fetch individual records with `Sod.objects.get(id=1)` for object number 1 etc.

Comment: How to make `dept-bp` as a unique index? Am bit new to Django and python

Comment: looking for a way to address individual records, so that I can update the records under one `dept-bp` pair value

Comment: There will be 30 records under that particulat `dept-bp` pair. Dept - is a database field and bp is another database filed

Answer (score 0):

In Django, every table in the database will automatically have a column called `id`. That is the default `primary key` column and unique for every object in a table.

So you can do

```
Sod_object = Sod.objects.get(id=1)
```

to fetch the first object in your table.

To update all the 30 objects for your `dept-bp` combination, you can `filter()` by those values

```
sods = Sod.objects.filter(dept=dept_name, bp=bp_name)
```

and then update each one and save. Django will internally remember the individual records by their `id`.

```
for sod in sods:
    sod.o = 1
    sod.save()
```